# The dimension of vector spaces whose null spaces are non-trival

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

## Original Question

$L(V, W)$ denotes the linear transformations from $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ to $m$ dimensional vector space $W$.
Let $U$ be a subset of $L(V,W)$, such that:
$$
U = \{ T\in L(V,W) \vert \exists v \in V: (v\neq 0)\wedge Tv = 0,  \}
$$
Is $U$ a subspace of $L(V,W)$?
If it is, what's the dimension of $U$?

---

However, it seems that the $U$ in the original question is not a subspace at all.
There is another question:

---

## New Question

Let $V$ denote an $n$ dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$, and $U$ denote an $m$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. $v \in V$ is a vector.

$L(V, W)$ denotes the linear transformations from $V$ to $W$.
Let $U$ be a subset of $L(V,W)$, such that:
$$
U = \{ T\in L(V,W) \vert  Tv = 0  \}
$$
Is $U$ a subspace of $L(V,W)$?
If it is, what's the dimension of $U$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $m < n$ then $U=L(V,W)$ of course. Any info on the relation between $m$ and $n$?

Comment: It's clearer to write $U=\{T \in L(V,W)\mid \exists v \in V: (v \neq 0) \land Tv =0\}$

Comment: Thank you, @HennoBrandsma. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use $U_v$ instead of $U$ to emphasize that it depends on $v$. Also we should assume that $v\neq 0$, otherwise $U_v=L(V,W)$.

Consider the following map:

$$P_v:L(U,W)\to W$$
$$P_v(T)=Tv$$

and note that this is a linear map. Moreover it is surjective if $v\neq 0$, which I leave as a simple exercise.

Furthermore $U_v=\ker P_v$ and thus it is clearly a linear subspace. Finally by the first isomorphism theorem we get $W\simeq L(U,W)/\ker P_v$ which implies

$$\dim U_v=\dim L(U,W)-\dim W$$

in finite dimensional case. Note that the dimension doesn't depend on the choice of $v$.

> However, it seems that the $U$ in the original question is not a subspace at all.

It rarely is. Consider $V=W=k^2$ and let $f, g:V\to W$ be given by $f(a,b)=(a,0)$, $g(a,b)=(0,b)$. Note that both $f,g$ belong to the original $U$, but $f+g$ does not belong to it, because $f+g$ is the identity.

This example can be generalized to any case with $2\leq \dim V\leq \dim W$. When $\dim W<\dim V$ then $U=L(V,W)$.